# nextSibling issue, should be simple

Tags: javascript, siblings

Ok, I'm trying to come to grips with this nextSibling function in JS.  Here's my issue within the following code...

```
var fromRow = document.getElementById("row_1");

while(fromRow.nodeType == 1 && fromRow.nextSibling != null)
{
    var fRowId = fromRow.id;
    if (!fRowId) continue;

    // THIS ONLY gets done once and alerts "row_1" ONLY :(
    alert(fRowId);

    fromRow = fromRow.nextSibling;
}
```

Ok can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code?  There are siblings next to this `document.getElementById("row_1");` element for sure as I can see them, and they all have id attributes, so why is it not getting the id attributes of the siblings??  I don't get it.

`row_1` is a `TR` element, and I need to get the `TR` elements next to it within this table, but for some reason, it only gets the 1 element that I can already get using `document.getElementById`, arggg.

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var fromRow = document.getElementById("row_1");

while(fromRow !== null)
{
    var fRowId = fromRow.id;
    if (!fRowId || fromRow.nodeType != 1) {
        fromRow = fromRow.nextSibling;
        continue;
    }

    // THIS ONLY gets done once and alerts "row_1" ONLY :(
    alert(fRowId);
    fromRow = fromRow.nextSibling;
}
```

While `fromRow.nextSibling != null` would halt on the second to last iteration because you already set `fromRow` to its `nextSibling` at the end.  Also, you don't necessarily want to halt if the next node isn't an element, you just want to move onto the next one if possible.  Finally, if you hit the `continue` in your original example, you'll run into an endless loop because `fromRow` would never change value.

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop stops as soon as it encounters a node not of type 1. So if there is any whitespace between your  elements the while loop will break after the first element.

What you probably want is:

```
while(fromRow.nextSibling != null)
{
    if(fromRow.nodeType == 1) {
        ...
    }
}
```